# debug a .dll compressed with pe compact

Tags: ida, ollydbg, pe, unpacking, patch-reversing

I am trying to load a DLL in IDA and OllyDbg, but it says the file is compressed. I checked with a couple of tools and came to know that the file is compressed with PECompact. I think it also has reverse-engineer protection enabled because debuggers are not able to load it but other tools can disassemble it.

So, my question is how do I unpack the DLL and start debugging ?

Comment: Check here as there are several tools that deal with that packer: http://www.woodmann.com/collaborative/tools/index.php/Category:Unpacking_Tools

Answer (score 3):

There exist unpackers for PECompact.

Try unpecompact2, I think there are two versions.
http://www.woodmann.com/collaborative/tools/index.php/UnPECompact2_(MadMickael_version)
http://www.woodmann.com/collaborative/tools/index.php/UnPECompact2_(smola_version)

If those doesn't work, you can try generic unpacker such as [RL!dePacker](http://rce.su/rldepacker/), [linxerUnpacker](http://www.xuetr.com/?p=11), [Quick Unpack](http://qunpack.ahteam.org/)

Comment: This answer is not constructive, what exactly someone can learn from it otherwise the strings to search for. Can you please post some meaningful links/data that can help others get an actual answer?

Answer (score 1):

As I never worked with PECompact before I downloaded a few unpackmes and tested it.  It looks like a very easy system to unpack.

The script [PeCompact 2.xx - 3.xx OEP Finder](https://tuts4you.com/download.php?view.2932) by atom0s found the OEP correctly for every unpackme I tested.  Please note that you will need to ignore a couple of exceptions (INT3 breaks and Memory access violations), but the anti-debugging will be defeated by the `DBH` instruction in ODBGScript.

For some of the unpackmes I found a simple API redirection was also present: each reference to the KERNEL32 API was redirected to a couple of instructions where the correct value was loaded in EAX followed by a `JMP EAX` instruction (see image):

[image: API redirection]

For such cases, I wrote this small script to solve the redirection (You will need to set the hard-coded value to the address of the first wrong entry):

```
var oep
var next

mov oep, eip
mov next, 00460974  // FIXME

FIX:
    mov eip, [next]
    sto
    mov [next], eax
    add next, 4
    cmp [next], 0
    jne FIX

mov eip, oep
ret
```

Once this second script is completed you can dump the file and fix the IAT as usual.

Also, it is not clear in your post if your problems are due to the fact that you are working on a DLL instead of an EXE file. If that's the case, you can either use the [LOADDLL tool](http://www.ollydbg.de/Loaddll.htm) or modify the PE header to load the DLL as an EXE (Here is an [example](http://www.pctools.com/security-news/unpacking-a-suspicious-dll/) of how to do it on LordPE).

Comment: I just noticed that Scylla and ImpREC have plugins to fix the IAT redirection on PECompact.  Therefore, my second script is not really needed.